# RPGLE opcodes - operating systems compatibility

Tags: operating-system, compatibility, ibm-midrange, opcode, rpgle

I'd like to know where to find a "table" that lets me know if a specific opcode is compatible with a specific version of the IBMi O.S.

Example:

> LEAVESR introduced in V4R4

Is there anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything quite as specific as your question, but all elements are documented in a similar way in the [ILE RPG Reference manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/rpgrnewrel.htm). The link is for ILE RPG for IBM i 7.3, but earlier releases have the same section according to the release. So, having just the latest gives you essentially the complete list of changes for all releases.

If you download a .PDF every few versions/releases, you can have a full history of "What's New" even if some future release truncates the section. If you think over the latest section, it should become clear that just having new op-codes isn't totally sufficient.

Comment: I knew the What's new section in the Knowledge center, but hoped on something "better". Anyways I'll build my table based on these! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This may be of use to you. [This page](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/opcgen.htm#opcgen) is a list of operation codes available to the RPG compiler in IBM i 7.3. There is a dropdown towards the top that let's you select a different OS version.

This would allow you to compare operation codes between OS versions.

You can also use this [What's New](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzasd/rpgrnewrel.htm) page to see every version back to V3R2.

Comment: Unfortunately, the release drop-down only works starting in 7.2. Prior to 7.2, the names of the html files for each page were different each release, and the release drop-down only works when the html file names are the same. For example, the opcodes page is called opcgen.html in 7.2 and 7.3, but it's called sc092508793.htm in 7.1, and some other similar but different name in 6.1.